# Why is print '\n' and print '\\n' showing same output in PHP?

Tags: php, string

```
<?php
print '\n';
print '\\n';
?>
```

For the above php code, i got output the following output:(http://ideone.com/vKRtgb)

```
\n\n
```

So, what is the difference between `print'\n'` and `print'\\n'` ?
I know that singly quoted strings are treated literally, but I expected the output to be `\n\\n` instead of `\n\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in [single-quoted strings in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single) can only escape single quotes and backslashes. Use double-quoted strings for escaping other characters like `\n`.

From the PHP documentation linked above:

> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\). To specify a literal backslash, double it (\\). All other instances of backslash will be treated as a literal backslash: **this means that the other escape sequences you might be used to, such as \r or \n, will be output literally as specified rather than having any special meaning**.

Answer (score 0):

PHP only interprets escaped characters (with the exception of the escaped backslash \ and the escaped single quote \') when in double quotes (")